# Using if function to remove invalid answers from survey data

Tags: r, survey

I'm trying to remove specific values from some variables (i.e. "99" corresponding to a "don't know" response on a survey item); but rather than renaming values greater than the max point on each scale (got 3 variables) as "N/A" and then exclude NAs - how could I do this in one step?

Also, my variables are integers, but need to set them to numeric and R won't let me (if I use the code below), the error message says "Problem with `mutate()` input `polintr`. x Input `polintr` can't be recycled to size 49519. i Input `polintr` is `as.numeric(data_s$polintr)`. i Input `polintr` must be size 49519 or 1, not 0." - but the polintr item has values from 1 to 4

```
data_s <- data_s %>%
  mutate(polintr = as.numeric(data_s$polintr)) +
  mutate(cptppola = as.numeric(data_s$cptppola)) +
  mutate(cptppola = as.numeric(data_s$cptppola))
_s$cptppola)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Ronak is right, particularly about your second question. Your first question sounds like you could use `dplyr::filter(data_s, variable == 99)` (although you might need `"99"` if it is treated as a character)